# why specified date events are not retrieved?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, wmi

the following code works when the timewritten <='20130215'.

```
  WqlObjectQuery query = new WqlObjectQuery("select * from win32_NTLogEvent where logfile='Application'  and type='information' and **timewritten<='20130214'** and eventcode='1022'");*emphasized text*
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach(ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Log file: " + mo["logfile"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Event type: "+mo["type"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Event Code: " + mo["eventcode"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Time generated: " + mo["timegenerated"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Event Source: "+mo["Sourcename"]);
 }
```

when the timewritten is tested as below wont work,

```
   timewritten <='20130214' 
   timewritten ='20130214'
```

can you tell me the reason  why it happend.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When does it work and when does it not work??

Answer (score 0):

[`timewritten`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a `datetime` value - it has a time component. If you don't specify a time component in a literal that's converted to a `datetime`, you get the midnight at the start of that day.

`timewritten ='20130214'` would ask for any events that happened at *exactly* midnight on the 14th.

`timewritten <='20130214'` asks for any events that happened *before* the 14th, or at *exactly* midnight on the 14th.

If you don't have any events that match those descriptions, you won't get any results.

If, as I suspect, you want all events that happened on the 14th, no matter at what time, you'd be best with `timewritten >= '20130214' and timewritten < '20130215'`